# Angular 4 - Resolver and Lazy Load strategy

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I got a very interesting scenario in our app which uses lazy loading strategy where our API based URL is being loaded from a GET request. The reason we decided to go with this approach is that we would like to build our app and deploy it to any environment (with different API location) without hard-coded the API based URL.

Im thinking to make the first GET request to server to obtain the API based URL then set based url to HTTPWrapper service. All subsequence HTTP requests will then follow that based URL.

Now, where would be the best place to implement the first HTTP request?

Can we create a `UniversalResolve` service and use it in all top level routing?

```
   export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMath: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule', resolve :{ data : UniversalResolve} },
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule', resolve :{ data : UniversalResolve} }
    ];
```

As you can see `UniversalResolve` are being applied to all highest level, which will cause GET request to obtain API based URL repeated everything we switch the page from Home to Admin then back to Home etc.

Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: why do you need to use `resolve` instead of simply defining a service? you can then use [APP_INITIALIZER](https://blog.angularindepth.com/hooking-into-the-angular-bootstrap-process-36e82a01fba8#2930) to delay application start until you get the data

Comment: Thanks for the input. I can actually inject an ApiService in the app component which potentially do 2 things at: One - get api based URL and set it to httpwrapper. Two - get all reference data through httpwrapper. The problem I am getting is that all GET methods retrieve reference data trigger before the based URL get set.